# Tailwind css "file dose not exist problem"

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBkZS.png)
please help me

Iam trying to set up tailwind css with cli but I go error.

Comment: You seemed to have misspelled "tailwind.css" in your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check the name of the file you specified in your code according to your screenshot.

It should be `tailwind.css` and not `taildwind.css`